# Yakuake settings not being applied in 18.04

Tags: kde, 18.04, yakuake

Yakuake doesn't apply settings from config on ubuntu 18.04, I looked around and found that there was a kde bug related to this so I also created a profile in `.local/share/konsole` and the settings are saved there but somehow yakuake doesn't apply the settings defined there.

I tried configuring it to always show on screen 2, if I change it from the UI, it moves to screen 2 but if I press F12 to hide/show it again it goes back to screen 1, but somehow the setting still shows as screen 2.

I have same settings in 2 places `.config/yakuakerc` and `.local/share/konsole/myprofile`

Here are the settings,

```
[Appearance]
BackgroundColor=136,138,133
BackgroundColorOpacity=5
Translucency=true

[Desktop Entry]
DefaultProfile=Leonidas.profile

[Dialogs]
FirstRun=false

[Favorite Profiles]
Favorites=

[Shortcuts]
close-active-terminal=Ctrl+Shift+R
close-session=Ctrl+Shift+W
decrease-window-height=Alt+Shift+Up
decrease-window-width=Alt+Shift+Left
file_quit=Ctrl+Shift+Q
grow-terminal-bottom=Ctrl+Alt+Down
grow-terminal-left=Ctrl+Alt+Left
grow-terminal-right=Ctrl+Alt+Right
grow-terminal-top=Ctrl+Alt+Up
increase-window-height=Alt+Shift+Down
increase-window-width=Alt+Shift+Right
move-session-left=Ctrl+Shift+Left
move-session-right=Ctrl+Shift+Right
new-session=Ctrl+Shift+T
next-session=Shift+Right
next-terminal=Ctrl+Shift+Down
previous-session=Shift+Left
previous-terminal=Ctrl+Shift+Up
rename-session=Ctrl+Alt+S
split-left-right=Ctrl+(
split-top-bottom=Ctrl+)
toggle-session-monitor-activity=Ctrl+Shift+A
toggle-session-monitor-silence=Ctrl+Shift+I
view-full-screen=Ctrl+Shift+F11

[Window]
Height=100
Position=51
Screen=2
ShowOnAllDesktops=false
Width=100
```

Comment: Perhaps its not relevant but is this a fresh **18.04** install or did you upgrade from an earlier version? If an upgrade from a working version, which one? Also you could try a fresh **16.04** install if you have nothing invested in **18.04** yet.

Comment: This is a fresh install, I was using 16.04 but I did not upgrade from it and I don't want to go back to 16.04, everything but this one feature is fine and working for me, thanks for the reply anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It seems clear to me that this is a bug.  There are no fewer than 3 bug reports for this issue, going back to January 2015:

https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=343434

https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=374504

https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=383555

This affects me as well, and I have just commented on the oldest bug report.

Comment: Yes this is so frustrating, I have been using Yakuake for so long and really don't want to switch

Answer (score 0):

1. `.local/share/konsole/myprofile` shoule be renamed to `.local/share/konsole/my.profile` (use `profile` as extension)
2. There should be a `[General]` section in the `my.profile`:

   ```
   [General]
   Name=Subash
   Parent=FALLBACK/
   ```

Comment: `myprofile` was just an example, I do have profiles with `.profile` extension in that location with `General` section